# What is difference between u-boot.bin and u-boot.rom

Tags: u-boot

I have builded the U-boot for minnowboard max. I am seeing the files like uboot.rom  uboot.bin etc.

what is the difference between uboot.rom and uboot.bin ? Which files I should flash to SPI NOR flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in doc/README.x86.  In short, if you are going to be writing U-Boot to SPI NOR then you need to ensure that you have the correct binary blobs in the correct locations AND use BUILD_ROM=y so that u-boot.rom is generated as this is the file that is required on x86 to run on bare metal (rather than say as a coreboot payload).

Edit to address the comment:
The file 'u-boot' is the ELF object that is the result of building all of the U-Boot sources and linking them.  This includes all of the extra sections and information an ELF file can contain.  This is also by and large not bootable.  The u-boot.bin file is the ELF u-boot but passed via objcopy to strip out (by and large, see the Makefile for the various flags or build with V=1) everything except for text/data sections so that we have only what is required to boot.  Then u-boot.rom is the combination of objects and formatting that the x86 architecture requires in order to execute and run an image.  Building with V=1 will show all of the details here.

Comment: Ya I have followed the instructions as per the document and genertaed the u-boot.rom. Got a doubt whats the difference between u-boot.rom ,uboot and u-boot.bin files as in that document nothing is mentioned about these files